# Centering different size photos when open in a pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **3 columns** in my gallery. The problem is with centering photos when you open them in a pop up window (I have js for that). So I need when i open my photo, to center every image based on it's size.

**Note:** You can only help me with changing my code, not with sending link for centering things, because i tried everything.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLYByG)

```
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLYByG][1]
```

Comment: Your problem is with your mess over caption width plus specified padding.

if you need padding then instead of:

    `.popup figure figcaption {width: 100%;}`

use this:

    `.popup figure figcaption {left: 0; right: 0;}`

Comment: Please include the relevant piece of your code inside your questions. Only links should not be used as they can make your question useless if they go offline.